# How to read the contents of a file In Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I know you can do something like this:

```
readlines(FileName) ->
    {ok, Device} = file:open(FileName, [read]),
    get_all_lines(Device, []).

get_all_lines(Device, Accum) ->
    case io:get_line(Device, "") of
        eof  -> file:close(Device), Accum;
        Line -> get_all_lines(Device, Accum ++ [Line])
    end.
```

Is there a one liner BIF that can do this too?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[file:read_file/1](http://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#read_file-1) is what you are looking for. Just for teaching purpose, `Accum ++ [Line]` is bad practice. Problem is that left argument of `++` is copied and right is used as is. In your code you will copy bigger and bigger part in each iteration. Solution is `lists:reverse(Line,Accum)` and than return `lists:reverse(Accum)` in your `eof` branch (Or `[Line|Accum]` and `lists:append(lists:reverse(Accum))` at the `eof` or use binary which have better append operation or ...). Another way is not using tail recursive function which is not so bad as seems at first time according to [Myth: Tail-recursive functions are MUCH faster than recursive functions](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/myths.html#tail_recursive).

So your `readlines/1` function should look like

```
readlines(FileName) ->
    {ok, Device} = file:open(FileName, [read]),
    try get_all_lines(Device)
      after file:close(Device)
    end.

get_all_lines(Device) ->
    case io:get_line(Device, "") of
        eof  -> [];
        Line -> Line ++ get_all_lines(Device)
    end.
```

Comment: Is not file:read_file a bit dangerous? I mean it is using file_server which looks like it's blocking (gen_server which is wrapping prim_file). It looks like prim_file or file_io_server could be better solutions.

Comment: I have not experienced or heard about any problem with `file:read_file`. I don't understand what it should blocking.

Answer (score 11):

You could leverage `file:read_file/1` and `binary:split/3` to do this work in two steps:

```
readlines(FileName) ->
    {ok, Data} = file:read_file(FileName),
    binary:split(Data, [<<"\n">>], [global]).
```

Comment: You really want to do a case statement here, because the file could not exist. case file:read_file(FileName) of {ok, Data} -> ... {error, _} -> ... end.

Comment: @MatthewDaiter No, let it crash.