# Erlang try - catch - after when reading files

Tags: file, io, erlang, try-catch

I took a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475270/how-to-read-the-contents-of-a-file-in-erlang) and believe I understand the solution, except for the following:

```
try get_all_lines(Device)
    after file:close(Device)
end.
```

Looking in the [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html), specifically the **7.19 Try** section, it looks like one would typically use `after` clauses as a failsafe block to execute regardless of the execution of a conditional block. If that is a correct assumption, why would the given example use `after` when, not only is there not a conditional block, there's not a block at all! It just looks like the `try get_all_lines(Device)` block is completely empty, and an unnecessary `after` clause was appended. Am I misinterpreting the example, or could this code be written better?

Answer (score 1):

The block isn't empty, it contains a single function call: `get_all_lines(Device)`. If `io:get_line` inside this function throws an exception (e.g. because the file was deleted while reading it, then `get_all_lines` will throw as well, and you need to close the file both in this case and when the function returns without an exception. This is precisely what `after` is for.

Comment: What is important to understand this code is that the return value of the "after" is lost, the whole expression has the same result than `try get_all_lines(Device)`. This is a bit weird compare to usage in erlang, but clearly explained in documentation  [reference_manual/expressions](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id79430).